# How can I make pdf file readable only by my app?

Tags: android

Is it possible to download a PDF from server and save in format that only my application can read?

Comment: You can use internal storage. But if the user roots his phone, he will be able to get your file.

So, you can encrypt your file. And decrypt it into memory (RAM) when the user wants to read the file. You can easily convert your PDF to HTML, and use WebView to display it. You can try googling for encrypting/ decrypting in Java.

Comment: can you please put some code, so that i can try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my working example used in my app ....hope this help you

> Is it possible to download pdf from server and save

Yes i have use **retrofit** library to download pdf file from server you can use **Volly** or **Loopj AsyncTask**  as well

After downloading pdf file you will get InputeStream object of file than encrypt that and store in app private folder (so no other application can able to use it)

```
public static File encryptAndSaveFileInPrivateFolder(
            Context context, String albumName, InputStream inputStream, String fullFileName) {
        File file = null;
        try {
            // Get the directory for the app's private pictures directory.
            File fileDirectory = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),""+albumName);
            if (!fileDirectory.exists()) {
                fileDirectory.mkdirs();
            }

            file = new File(fileDirectory,""+fullFileName);
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
            }
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
            encrypt(inputStream,output);
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file;
    }
```

**This method encrypt your file**

```
public static void encrypt(InputStream fis,FileOutputStream fos ) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
            , NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
        // Here you read the cleartext.
        //FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("data/cleartext");
        // This stream write the encrypted text. This stream will be wrapped by another stream.
        // FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("data/encrypted");

        String password ="passwordProtectd";
        // Length is 16 byte
        byte[] inputByte = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(inputByte, "AES");
        // SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(password.getBytes(), "AES");
        // Create cipher
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
        // Wrap the output stream
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
        // Write bytes
        int b;
        byte[] d = new byte[8];
        while((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
            cos.write(d, 0, b);
        }
        // Flush and close streams.
        cos.flush();
        cos.close();
        fis.close();
    }
```

**Than show pdf using intent**

```
public void decryptFileAndShow(Context context,File mFile) {
        try{
            if (null != mFile) {
                String parentPath = mFile.getAbsoluteFile().getParent();//Actual encrypted file path
                File tempFile = new File(parentPath, "report.pdf"); //Created new file that decrypted format after view we will delete this
                //tempFile =File.createTempFile("prefix","TestMyPDF.pdf", context.getExternalFilesDir(""));
                Utilities.decrypt( new FileInputStream(mFile), new FileOutputStream(tempFile));


                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(tempFile), "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                tempFile.deleteOnExit();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**Last the method used for decryption**

```
public static void decrypt(FileInputStream fis,FileOutputStream fos ) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
        // FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("data/encrypted");
        // FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("data/decrypted");
        String password ="passwordProtectd";
        byte[] inputByte = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(inputByte, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
        int b;
        byte[] d = new byte[8];
        while((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
            fos.write(d, 0, b);
        }
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        cis.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Is it possible to download pdf from server.
```

Yes, it is possible. Download your pdf and encrypt and decrypt your file accordingly.

You can try like this using CipherOuputStream and CipherInputStream:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
```

Encryption:

```
public void encrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
    try {
        // Bytes written to out will be encrypted
        out = new CipherOutputStream(out, ecipher);

        // Read in the cleartext bytes and write to out to encrypt
        int numRead = 0;
        while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Decryption:

```
public void decrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
    try {
        // Bytes read from in will be decrypted
        in = new CipherInputStream(in, dcipher);

        // Read in the decrypted bytes and write the cleartext to out
        int numRead = 0;
        while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want your application to be the only application that reads this particular PDF files. You want to know how you can ensure that you do that.

Since your requirement is not genuine(hacky), the solution also has to be a bit hacky.

You can download the file and store it with your own custom extension (eg. file.mypdf)

Have an intent filter, that supports mimetypes matching **.mypdf** files

Answer (score 0):

You could have the server encrypt the download and your client side app decrypt it using a public/private key pair. This would prevent anyone with a snooping proxy from observing and saving your content, but it wouldn't deter the most determined users from stealing these documents as they would eventually exist in decrypted form somewhere. To achieve that you'd probably ave to create your own PDF viewer and damage the bytes of the PDF in a way that your viewer can do, but no other viewer can recover